# Users\bots hitting weird urls on my site

Tags: website, bots

Few times a day every day I get something hitting my site on urls like this:

/MSOffice/cltreq.asp?UL=1&ACT=4&BUILD=6551&STRMVER=4&CAPREQ=0 
/_vti_bin/owssvr.dll?UL=1&ACT=4&BUILD=6551&STRMVER=4&CAPREQ=0

The user agent is this:
UserAgent Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; InfoPath.1; OfficeLiveConnector.1.3; OfficeLivePatch.0.0)

Looks like some sort of Microsoft bot? What its trying to do.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is related to the [Web Discussions Toolbar that comes with Office 2003](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/help/HP030701131033.aspx) which is an add-in to Internet Explorer.  [IE is querying your site to see if it supports the extensions required to support this.](http://www.planetmike.com/2008/03/14/ms-office-discussion-bar/)

The only thing you can do to mitigate the problem is create `/MSOffice/cltreq.asp` as a zero length file on your server as this will be quicker to serve than a 404 page.

Comment: You beat me by a minute +1

Answer (score 0):

It's not a bot.

Your users have Microsoft Office installed, and the discussion bar turned on in IE. IE is querying the server to see whether it supports web discussions.

Answer (score 0):

These requests are generated when someone browses your site with Internet Explorer's Discussion toolbar enabled. You can safely ignore these requests.

http://www.msoffice-cltreq-asp.info/

http://www.michaelteper.com/archive/2005/11/02/4276.aspx